# How to maximize logcat's windows on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

The title said it all,

How to maximize logcat's windows on android studio?

Right now my logcat's windows is very small and i need to scroll it to view it's message.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the resize pane handles to make it bigger, or use the settings option (a cog icon on the right of the DDMS pane) to choose floating mode, and maximise that window.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D I wonder why they dont just add the maximize menu

Answer (score 1):

I have indicated all the trivial steps to be sure to fit every preset configuration of Android Studio, once implemented will take roughly 200 milliseconds to maximize Logcat!

The document is divided in **Settings**( to do only one time) and then **The real shortcut** ( to do once the settings are in memory):

**Settings**:

1)Alt+6  to open the Android debug window( you do not need this step if you are in the middle of the debugging, namely if you pressed the debug button)

2)Drag with the mouse the tab logcat putting it in front of the others( probably ADB logs, Memory, CPU for android studio 1.3.1), in this way the system will remember this preset.

**The real shortcut:**

When you are in debug mode, press Alt+6 (in the case Logcat is not appearing as main table),and CTLR+SHIFT+quote         *where quote  means the **"** Quote Key*

LOGCAT will be maximized, to switch to debug alt+5, no need to press again Ctrl+Shift+Quote! Please notice that if it is set Debug only this application from the dropdown menu you won't see a lot of events, so it is up to you to decide to select No Filters (if you want to see the Error only,Tab in the Dropdown menu where is written Verbose and change it with Error.)

**All in all once the settings are correct Alt+6-->Ctrl+Shift+Quote( to maximize)-->Alt+5 to go back on the debugger table**

EDIT: There is a second possibility depends by your taste: from the main Debug screen ( Table Debugger) you can press Ctrl+Shift+Quote  then the key TAB, and then Arrow Right, Left to switch between Logcat,Debugger and Console. Personally I use this option only when I have a long debug because is useful to switch between Debugger and Logcat with Alt+Arrow

Answer (score 0):

Even better (on OS X at least, perhaps others?):  SHIFT-COMMAND-' toggles maximize / minimize